# TypeError: response2.json is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, fetch, anonymous

I'm trying to use anonymous functions to get two datasets. using two fetch call the second call depending on the 1st and the second is a loop I Keep get a err on the second call response2.json is not a function

```
    async function example() {
    let response1 = await fetch(
        `https://www.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=9c348b767f7a0403e907b0788188afba&text=observatory&accuracy=+11&media=photos+&geo_context=1&lat=41.8989&lon=-87.6123&radius=25&radius_units=km&extras=&format=json&nojsoncallback=1`
    );
    let json = await response1.json();
    console.log(json.photos.photo);

    const response2 = await json.photos.photo.map((i) =>
        fetch(
            `https://www.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.geo.getLocation&api_key=9c348b767f7a0403e907b0788188afba&photo_id=${i.id}&format=json&nojsoncallback=1`
        )
    );


    const json2 = await response2.json();
    console.log(json2);
    return {
        dataset1: json,
        dataset2: json2
    };
}
```

Comment: `response2` will be an array of fetch responses - an array is not a fetch response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const response2 = await json.photos.photo.map(fetch('yourUrl'))
```

Here what follows up `await` is an array, not a promise
So maybe you can use Promise.all to wrap up this array.
But `fetch` is a little special than common promise.

```
const response2 = await Promise.all(json.photos.photo.map(fetch('yourUrl')));
const responseVirtual = response2.map(res => res.json());
```

May it help you, bro

Comment: change `Promise.call` to `Promise.all` :D

Comment: @VivekDoshi sorry, it's a typo

Comment: You also need to call fetch inside map, as both URLs are diff

Answer (score 2):

**Issue**

`response2` is array of promises,

`await json.photos.photo.map` will not make inner request synchronous,

```
const response2 = await json.photos.photo.map((i) =>
        fetch(
            `https://www.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.geo.getLocation&api_key=9c348b767f7a0403e907b0788188afba&photo_id=${i.id}&format=json&nojsoncallback=1`
        )
    );
```

**Solution :**

```
const promises = json.photos.photo.map((i) =>
    fetch(
        `https://www.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.geo.getLocation&api_key=9c348b767f7a0403e907b0788188afba&photo_id=${i.id}&format=json&nojsoncallback=1`
    )
));

// get all response from promises
const response2 = await Promise.all(promises)

// response2 is array of responses , so we need to loop through it
const json2 = await Promise.all(response2.map(res => res.json()));
```